# Not able to print python function in R

Tags: r

I have declared a python function in R, but not able to call it in R. Not sure what wrong I am doing. Below is the reprex....................................

ui.R file

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(reticulate)
source_python("python.py")

dashboardPage(  

  header <- dashboardHeader(disable = TRUE),

  dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE),

  body <- dashboardBody(fluidRow(

          fluidRow(
          column(width = 12,actionButton("upload","Upload Text",width = 150)),
          column(width = 12,actionButton("clear_upload","Clear Output",width = 150))
        ),
        br(),
        verbatimTextOutput("code")
      )
      )
      )
```

server.R

```
server <- function(input, output,session) {
   get_code <- eventReactive(input$upload,{
      py$happyBirthday('Andre')
   })

   observeEvent(input$upload, {
      output$code <- renderPrint(get_code())
   })

   observeEvent(input$clear_upload, {
      output$code <- renderPrint("")
   })
}
```

python.py

```
def happyBirthday(person):
    print("Happy Birthday to you!")
    print("Happy Birthday to you!")
    print("Happy Birthday, dear " + person + ".")
    print("Happy Birthday to you!")
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is **not** that you are not able to call the function, the problem is that you use `print` in the function definiton of `happyBirthday`. But you should use `return`!
If I replace the content of 'python.py' with

```
def happyBirthday(person):
    return("Happy Birthday to you!")
```

I get the expected result.

Comment: Sorry did not get you. Is  this wrong ```` get_code <- eventReactive(input$upload,{
      py$happyBirthday('Andre')
   })````

Comment: I did not change anything else than the function definition in python.py. 

To replicate my change do the following:

1. Change the content of python.py to the code as suggested in my answer.
2. Re-run the shiny app